# IntelliJ - Hotkey for add all final modifiers where possible?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, plugins, hotkeys

I've spent half my life in Eclipse, now transitioning to IntelliJ. Old habigs die hard :-)7

I really liked the functionality of Ctrl+A, Ctrl+1, add finals where possible to an extent it is in my muscle memory. Pls let's try to avoid the debate of usefulness/necessity. Pretty pls :-)

Is there a way to do the same in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- enable inspection "Preferences | Editor | Inspections | Java | Code style issues | Local variable or parameter can be 'final'", and run "Code | [Code Cleanup](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-problems.html#clean-up-code)"
- you can use "Code | [Reformat code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html)" with "Code cleanup" checked in the dialog
- also, you can make generated local variables and parameters final by default in "Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Code Generation"

Comment: Thx! Will check these options later today!